# Python how to add exception?

Tags: python, exception

@martineau I have updated my codes, is this what you meant ? How do i handle KeyError instead of NameError ?

```
url = "http://app2.nea.gov.sg/anti-pollution-radiation-protection/air-pollution/psi/psi-readings-over-the-last-24-hours"
web_soup = soup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

table = web_soup.find(name="div", attrs={'class': 'c1'}).find_all(name="div")[4].find_all('table')[0]

data = {}
cur_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("12AM", "%I%p")
for tr_index, tr in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')):
    if 'Time' in tr.text:
        continue
    for td_index, td in enumerate(tr.find_all('td')):
        if not td_index:
            continue
        data[cur_time] = td.text.strip()

        if td.find('strong'):
            bold_time = cur_time
            data[bold_time] = '20'
        cur_time += datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

        default_value = '20' # whatever you want it to be

    try:
        bold = data[bold_time]
    except NameError:

        bold_time = beforebold = beforebeforebold = default_value
    # might want to set "bold" to something, too, if needed
    else:   
        beforebold = data.get(bold_time - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)) 
        beforebeforebold =  data.get(bold_time - datetime.timedelta(hours=2))
```

This is where I print my data to do calculation.

```
print bold
print beforebold
print beforebeforebold
```

Comment: What value should `bold` have if the `bold = data[bold_time]` statement raises a `NameError`?

Comment: bold = data[bold_time] should have the value of the word strong in the website http://app2.nea.gov.sg/anti-pollution-radiation-protection/air-pollution/psi/psi-readings-over-the-last-24-hours

Comment: Yes, but what do you want `bold` to be set to if the word strong is not found -- what should it's default value be in that case? This is needed to know what to set `beforebold` and `beforebeforebold` to when that happens, as well.

Comment: The word 'strong' is a sure have in the website, therefore i wanted to get the value for that and replace to beforebold and beforebeforebold. Any idea ?

Comment: I've removed my answer as you've no idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: If the word `strong` is sure to be there, why would you ever get a `NameError` from the `bold = data[bold_time]` statement? How does `data[bold_time]` get set?

Comment: To handle `KeyError` instead, change the `except NameError:` to `except KeyError:`. To _also_ handle it, add a separate `except KeyError:` clause. To handle both of them the same way use a single `except NameError, KeyError:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add something to set `data[bold_time]`:

```
    if td.find('strong'):
        bold_time = cur_time
        data[bold_time] = ????? # whatever it should be
    cur_time += datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

This should avoid both the `NameError` and `KeyError` exceptions as long as the word `strong` is found. You still might want to code defensively and handle one or both of them gracefully. That what exception where meant to do, handle those exceptional cases that shouldn't happen...

Comment: Your question says "bold = data[bold_time] **NameError**: name 'bold_time'"

Comment: I had a bold = data[bold_time] KeyError: 50 help, i set the default_value = '50'

Comment: I had this NameError: name 'bold_time' is not defined after i change to except KeyError

Comment: OK, I think the problem is you never set `data[bold_time]` as well as `bold_time` itself when you find word `strong`. Add a line following the `if td.find('strong'):` to set its value to a value, too.

Comment: I solved it, it is because of the indentation. Haha thanks a lot a lot a lot ! I really thanks you =)

Comment: All right then, you're welcome...I don't see how indentation could have been the problem -- at least in the code shown in your question -- but that's OK I guess.

Comment: I had this error now, how can i solve it ? bold = data[bold_time]
NameError: name 'bold_time' is not defined. I added what you written but still get this error

Comment: When i rename KeyError to NameError, it works fine, How do i solve the KeyError again if it occurs ? possible to add two exceptions ?

Comment: Right now i have 20, None, None when i print bold, beforebold and beforebeforebold. Help !

Comment: Referring to the code in your updated question: The `None` values for `beforebold` and `beforebeforebold` are because when you call `data.get(bold_time - datetime.timedelta(hours=1))` (or with `hours=2`) it's returning `None` because there's no key in the `data` dictionary with the value `bold_time - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)` (or `hours=2`).

Answer (score 0):

I had read your previous post before it disappeared, and then I've read this one.
I find it a pity to use BeautifulSoup for your goal, because, from the code I see, I find its use complicated, and the fact is that regexes run roughly 10 times faster than BeautifulSoup.

Here's the code with only `re`, that furnishes the data you are interested in.
I know, there will people to say that HTML text can't be parsed by regexs. I know, I know... but I don't parse the text, I directly find the chunks of text that are interesting. The source code of the webpage of this site is apparently very well structured and it seems there is little risk of bugs.  Moreover, tests and verification can be added to keep watch on the source code and to be instantly informed on the possible changings made by the webmaster in the webpage

```
import re
from httplib import HTTPConnection

hypr = HTTPConnection(host='app2.nea.gov.sg',
                      timeout = 300)
rekete = ('/anti-pollution-radiation-protection/'
          'air-pollution/psi/'
          'psi-readings-over-the-last-24-hours')

hypr.request('GET',rekete)
page = hypr.getresponse().read()


patime = ('PSI Readings.+?'
          'width="\d+%" align="center">\r\n'
          ' *<strong>Time</strong>\r\n'
          ' *</td>\r\n'
          '((?: *<td width="\d+%" align="center">'
          '<strong>\d+AM</strong>\r\n'
          ' *</td>\r\n)+.+?)'

          'width="\d+%" align="center">\r\n'
          ' *<strong>Time</strong>\r\n'
          ' *</td>\r\n'
          '((?: *<td width="\d+%" align="center">'
          '<strong>\d+PM</strong>\r\n'
          ' *</td>\r\n)+.+?)'
          'PM2.5 Concentration')
rgxtime = re.compile(patime,re.DOTALL)


patline = ('<td align="center">\r\n'
           ' *<strong>'             # next line = group 1
           '(North|South|East|West|Central|Overall Singapore)'
           '</strong>\r\n'
           ' *</td>\r\n'
           '((?: *<td align="center">\r\n'  # group 2 start
           ' *[.\d-]+\r\n'                  #
           ' *</td>\r\n)*)'                 # group 2 end

           ' *<td align="center">\r\n'
           ' *<strong style[^>]+>'
           '([.\d-]+)' # group 3
           '</strong>\r\n'
           ' *</td>\r\n')
rgxline = re.compile(patline)

rgxnb = re.compile('<td align="center">\r\n'
                   ' *([.\d-]+)\r\n'
                   ' *</td>\r\n')


m= rgxtime.search(page)

a,b = m.span(1) # m.group(1) contains the data AM
d = dict((mat.group(1),
          rgxnb.findall(mat.group(2))+[mat.group(3)])
         for mat in rgxline.finditer(page[a:b]))

a,b = m.span(2) # m.group(2) contains the data PM
for mat in rgxline.finditer(page[a:b]):
    d[mat.group(1)].extend(rgxnb.findall(mat.group(2))+[mat.group(3)])


print 'last 3 values'
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print '%s  :  %s' % (k,v[-3:])
```

Comment: @Help me And then , what ?